# Set Excel configuration for C# Interop app

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am working on a C#/Excel application for a client and I've had some problems when they have their Excel configuration different to mine (for instance a recent problem was occurring if they had set the default number of worksheets in a workbook to be different to 1).

As I am working on developing this application by myself and it's infeasible to generate a huge number of testing frameworks, is there any way to export my Excel configuration along with the application I develop, import this on their machine at runtime when I create the Excel instance in C# and then reset their configuration back to the original settings once my application closes?

Comment: what do you have so far in regards to `their  configuration  is different` are you hard coding ? can you show what you have tried.. ? and how come you can't give them the option to chose a certain number of worksheets and then pass that number into the `Interop` functionality...?

Comment: @MethodMan The concrete example I have found was the default number of worksheets but I was thinking of any of the configuration options in the Excel options menu that might be different. I agree that I could handle each case manually (as I have done for the case of differing numbers of worksheets) but working with a configuration file that would **guarantee** that the the working version of excel used the same version as I have would make testing the application much easier. Does that make sense?

Comment: I know it may be too late, but - maybe think about using EPplus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/). I think it could help you avoid the configuration problems you have.

Comment: have you thought about `OpenXML` that seems to work wonders in regards to different versions of Excel